# Software caused connection abort & Failed host lookup: 'api.xyz.io'

Tags: android, ios, flutter, http, crashlytics

I'm facing `Failed host lookup: 'api.xyz.io'` and `Software caused connection abort` some users on crashlytics logs. when i send http request on my app opening loading screen.

```
Non-fatal Exception: io.flutter.plugins.firebase.crashlytics.FlutterError: Software caused connection abort. Error thrown Init User.
       at IOClient.send(io_client.dart:88)
       at BaseClient._sendUnstreamed(base_client.dart:93)
       at get.<fn>(http_custom.dart:47)
       at ._withClient(http_custom.dart:256)
       at UserController.initUser(userController.dart:33)
       at LoadingScreenState.checkRequirements(loading_screen.dart:172)
       at LoadingScreenState.asyncInits(loading_screen.dart:121)
```

it is looking like connection problem but i am checking user network status before send request.
Other side I'm sending 3 request as a sync
1- check connection
2- initser
3- getsettings
ussualy stuck check connection not a problem (maybe connection lost), but wierd side sometimes check connection success, init user thrown `Failed host lookup: 'api.xyz.io'` somites all succes, getsettings stuck. it's so weird i think

```
Non-fatal Exception: io.flutter.plugins.firebase.crashlytics.FlutterError: Failed host lookup: 'api.xyz.io'. Error thrown Internet connection failed.
       at IOClient.send(io_client.dart:88)
       at BaseClient._sendUnstreamed(base_client.dart:93)
       at get.<fn>(http_custom.dart:47)
       at ._withClient(http_custom.dart:256)
       at ConnectionUtils.isConnected(connection_utils.dart:11)
```

All request similar like that

```
 try {
      final url = this.routes.userRoutes.getSettings;

      // Send the request
      final response = await httpCustom.get(
        url,
        headers: await HeaderUtils.authorizedGet(),
      );
      var responseJson = jsonDecode(response.body);

      User user = User.fromJson(responseJson['user']);
      Settings settings = Settings.fromJson(responseJson);
      await storage.write(key: StorageKeys().user, value: user.toString());
      await storage.write(
          key: StorageKeys().settings, value: settings.toString());
      sendSuccesLog(funcName: "initUser");
      return user;
    } catch (e, stack) {
      FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.recordError(e, stack, reason: 'Init User');
      checkNetworkConnection(funcName: "initUser");
      return null;
    }
```

I tried
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />`

and

`android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"`

and im using

https://pub.dev/packages/internet_connection_checker

Comment: Network preflight checks can be useful to inform the user that they have a network problem, but they do not guarantee that your network operation is going to succeed.  The network can fail at any moment; The user can enter a tunnel or enter an elevator, simply walk out of range of a buildings Wifi or there could be a power cut.  Another common scenario is being connected to a "hotspot" network with limited connectivity because the user has not yet authenticated.  In short, any network operation can fail at any time. You should handle it and retry or show an error to the user as appropriate

Comment: Yes, I agree that scenarios and i'm showing network connection problem message to user when first connection request fail. but interesting side when i'm in presentation i am showing app to user, connection check successed then second request throw no host lookup. Has nothing changes like location or something. But the problem not happens always ussualy %10 users happens.